# AWS glue write dynamic frame out of memory (OOM)

Tags: amazon-s3, memory-management, pyspark, out-of-memory, aws-glue

I am using AWS glue to run a pyspark to read a dynamic frame from catalog (data in redshift),then write it to s3 in csv format. I am getting this error saying the executor is out of memory:

```
An error occurred while calling o883.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 388 in stage 21.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 388.3 in stage 21.0 (TID 10713, ip-10-242-88-215.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 86): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 86 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 16.1 GB of 16 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
```

My guess is that the dataframe is not partitioned well before writing so one executor runs out of memory. But when I follow this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html to add partition keys to my dynamicframe, the job simply timeout after 4 hours. (The partition key I choose splits the data set into around 10 partitions)

Some other approaches I tried:

1. Trying to configure the fetchsize but the aws doc shows the glue has configure the fetchsize to 1000 by default.  [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-memory-management-in-aws-glue/#:~:text=With%20AWS%20Glue%2C%20Dynamic%20Frames,Spark%20executor%20and%20database%20instance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-memory-management-in-aws-glue/#:%7E:text=With%20AWS%20Glue%2C%20Dynamic%20Frames,Spark%20executor%20and%20database%20instance).
2. Trying to set pushdown predicates but the input dataset is created daily and not partitioned. I also need all rows to perform joins/filters in ETL so this might not be a good solution to me.

Does anyone know what are some good alternatives to try out?

Comment: tried different node types?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes, I have tried different worker type and scaled those with largest memory limit

Comment: @CinYi did you find solution for this ?